# Wordpress after checking username and password how log in

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i created this code below in my wordpress theme within my `login.php` page i created conditional statements successfully without any problem but in my last if statement when the username and password is correct i can't when this statement is correct i log in?

i want when the username and password is correct directly show legge in username and add the log out link to log out from the theme.

```
<?php
$error = '';
$success = '';
global $user_identity;

if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'login') {

    $username = esc_attr($_POST['login_username']);
    $password = esc_attr($_POST['login_password']);
    $remember = esc_attr($_POST['login_remember']);

    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);

    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;
    $user_pass  = $user_data->user_pass;

    if($username == '' && $password == '') {
        $error = 'Please Fill Required Fields!';
    }
    if($username == '') {
        $error = 'Please Enter Your Username';
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $error = 'Please Enter Your Password';
    }
    if($user_login != $username) {
        $error = 'The Username is Incorrect';
    }
    if($user_pass != $password) {
        $error = 'The Password is Incorrect';
    }
    if($user_login == $username && $user_pass == $password) {

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain. Are you trying to alter WordPress's `login.php` code? Or is the code in your question part of your plugin? It is probably a bad idea to alter WordPress's login code: cybercriminals are actively attacking all public WordPress installations they can find, and the WordPress developers are responding with plenty of security updates. You may introduce vulnerabilities into your site if you mess with this code.

Answer (score 0):

hey just create array of user data and passed into `wp_signon($data,false)` see below.

```
$login_data = array();
$login_data['user_login'] = $username;
$login_data['user_password'] = $password;
$login_data['remember'] = $remember; // set true or false for remember

$user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, false ); 

if ( is_wp_error($user_verify) ) 
{
    echo $user->get_error_message();
    exit;
 } else {    
   header("Location: " . home_url() . "/login/error/");
 }
```

read document for more detail [wp_signon()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)